# Copy join-query from database to another datable

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, dblink

Previously, I am using  dblink to achieve the mission but it involved copy one query only. What if I have doing the join query (4 tables) in one database, then i want to copy the data output into another database.Anyone know about it ?

```
select 
    a.sysname, a.ip, b.host_id, b.resource_name, b.resource_id
    , c.metric_id, d.metric_name,  c.value, c.resource_id
    , to_timestamp(c.date_id)as datetime 
from inv.el a 
inner join inv.if b on a.host_id = b.host_id 
inner join me.me_cr c on b.resource_id = c.resource_id 
inner join inv.me d on c.metric_id = d.metric_id 
where date_id = (
    select max(date_id) from me.me_cr
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `postgres_fdw` on Release > 9.6 as it

> ... now supports remote joins...

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6.html